# Why are tibbles slower than matrices in a for-loop but faster when accesses very often?

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, tidyverse, tibble

For an agent-based modelling project I was considering to use tidyverse's a `tibble` instead of a `matrix`. I checked the performance of both with a very simple ABM (see below) where I simulate a population, where individuals are ageing, dying, and being born. Typical for an ABM, I am using a for-loop and indexing.

When benchmarking the two data structures (see a graph here: https://github.com/marcosmolla/tibble_vs_matrix) the matrix is a lot faster than the tibble. However, for 10e6 runs this result is actually inverted. And I have no idea why.

It would be great to understand this result to inform whether or not I should use tibbles or matrices in the future for this kind of use case.

Thank you all for any input!

[image: fig1]

```r
# This code benchmarks the speed of tibbles versus matrices. This should be useful for evaluating the suitability of tibbles in a ABM context where matrix data is frequently altered in matrices (or vectors).

library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)
library(cowplot)

lapply(c(10^1, 10^2, 10^3, 10^4, 10^5, 10^6), function(runtime){
  # Set up tibble
  indTBL <- tibble(id=1:100,
         type=sample(1:3, size=100, replace=T),
         age=1)

  # Set up matrix (from tibble)
  indMAT <- as.matrix(indTBL)

  # Simulation run with tibble
  t <- Sys.time()
  for(i in 1:runtime){
    # increase age
    indTBL$age <- indTBL[["age"]]+1

    # replace individuals by chance or when max age
    dead <- (1:100)[runif(n=100,min=0,max=1)<=0.01 | indTBL[["age"]]>100]
    indTBL[dead, "age"] <- 1
    indTBL[dead, "type"] <- sample(1:3, size=length(dead), replace=T)
  }
  tibbleTime <- as.numeric(Sys.time()-t)

  # Simulation run with matrix
  t <- Sys.time()
  for(i in 1:runtime){
    # increase age
    indMAT[,"age"] <- indMAT[,"age"]+1

    # replace individuals by chance or when max age
    dead <- (1:100)[runif(n=100,min=0,max=1)<=0.01 | indMAT[,"age"]>100]
    indMAT[dead, "age"] <- 1
    indMAT[dead, "type"] <- sample(1:3, size=length(dead), replace=T)
  }
  matrixTime <- as.numeric(Sys.time()-t)

  # Return both run times
  return(data.frame(tibbleTime=tibbleTime, matrixTime=matrixTime))
}) %>% bind_rows() -> res

# Prepare data for ggplot
res$power <- 1:nrow(res)
res_m <- melt(data=res, id.vars="power")

# Line plot for results
ggplot(data=res_m, aes(x=power, y=value, color=variable)) + geom_point() + geom_line() + scale_color_brewer(palette="Paired") + ylab("Runtime in sec") + xlab(bquote("Simulation runs"~10^x))
```

Comment: Have you done any [profiling](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Profiling.html) yourself? That's usually a good place to start with something like this.

Comment: I suspect that it must be linked to the type checks that are performed on tibbles and `data.frame`s. While the matrix can only accept a single type (character or numeric) data.frame derived objects can accept more, so they check if you are able to perform the operation on the column. By the way I would recommend the bench package to precisely measure the time (maybe there is some memory clean up going on too that will show up if you use bench) .

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for your replies. I used the `microbenchmark` package to benchmark properly. Now, I find that for 10e6 runs a matrix is still faster.

```
  indTBL <- tibble(id=1:100,
                   type=sample(1:3, size=100, replace=T),
                   age=1)

  # Set up matrix (from tibble)
  indMAT <- as.matrix(indTBL)

  # Simulation run with tibble
  runtime <- 10^6
  microbenchmark(
  tib=for(i in 1:runtime){
    # increase age
    indTBL$age <- indTBL[["age"]]+1

    # replace individuals by chance or when max age
    dead <- (1:100)[runif(n=100,min=0,max=1)<=0.01 | indTBL[["age"]]>100]
    indTBL[dead, "age"] <- 1
    indTBL[dead, "type"] <- sample(1:3, size=length(dead), replace=T)
  },

  # Simulation run with matrix
  mat=for(i in 1:runtime){
    # increase age
    indMAT[,"age"] <- indMAT[,"age"]+1

    # replace individuals by chance or when max age
    dead <- (1:100)[runif(n=100,min=0,max=1)<=0.01 | indMAT[,"age"]>100]
    indMAT[dead, "age"] <- 1
    indMAT[dead, "type"] <- sample(1:3, size=length(dead), replace=T)
  }, times=1
  )
```

The result is

```r
Unit: seconds
 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
  tib 80.22042 81.45051 82.26645 82.68061 83.28946 83.89831     3   b
  mat 20.44746 20.66974 20.75168 20.89202 20.90378 20.91555     3  a
```

Thank you Ilrs and MrFlick for that hint.